# Why this code isn't causing endless recurssion

Tags: scala

I found this code online and I have some doubts regarding its syntax.

https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/master/play-mailer/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/mailer/MailerClient.scala

Question 1 - In line `import play.libs.mailer.{ Email => JEmail, MailerClient => JMailerClient }`
, I suppose this is import rename and `play.libs.mailer.Email` will be referred as `JEmail` and `play.libs.mailer.MailerClient` is being referred as `JMailerClient`. Why is the import been renamed?

Question 2 - In line `trait MailerClient extends JMailerClient`, the code uses both `MailerClient` and `JMailerClient` but isn't `MailerClient` same as `JMailerClient`

Question 3 - In the following code, `send` is undefined, then it is overriden and then in the overridden function, `send` is called again! How is it working?

```
def send(data: Email): String

  override def send(data: JEmail): String = {
    val email = convert(data)
    send(email)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If `play.libs.mailer.Email` were imported as `Email`, that would hide the `Email` class from this package. By importing the former as `JEmail`, the latter can still be referred to as `Email`. Similarly if `MailerClient` were imported without the "J", the `MailerClient` defined in this very file would just shadow it. Plus line 7 would turn into `trait MailerClient extends MailerClient`, which is obviously a problem because it now looks like the trait is trying to extend itself.
2. No. This definition defines a trait named `MailerClient`. That trait extends `JMailerClient` (a.k.a. `play.libs.mailer.MailerClient`). `MailerClient` is the trait being defined right here and `JMailerClient` is the interface that is being extended.
3. As you can see later in the file, `convert` returns an `Email` object. So the call `send(email)` does not recursively call the second `send` method (which takes a `JEmail`), but rather calls the overload for `Email` objects that's defined (as an abstract method) on line 15.

Comment: Many thanks. Well explained. So wherever I see `JMail`, I should read it as `play.libs.mailer.Email` and same for `JMailerClient`